# Is it possible to use only lookaround to match characters that are not repeated immediately before and after?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

For example, to match the first slash after the domain name in the URL.
Intent: Only match `'/'` in `'.com/...'` but not any `'/'` in `'https://'`.

```js
url = 'https://example.com/...';
[
url.match(       /(?<!\/)(?<slash>\/)(?!\k<slash>).../), // [A]
url.match(/(?<!\k<slash>)(?<slash>\/)(?!\k<slash>).../)  // [B]
]
```

The above [A] returns the correct match, but [B] is *the **kind** of expression* I want (although it did not match any characters), that is, to use the `/` character only **1 time** in the body of regex literals.

Is there a ***generalized** form of expression* similar to [B] (using capturing groups or the like) and using only regular expression **literals** (instead of using the constructor (`RegExp`))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a positive lookbehind after an optional character inside a negative lookahead. The lookbehind asserts 2 consecutive slashes (using a reference). This way the lookbehind tests the captured slash position and also the position before. Obviously, when it succeeds, the negative lookahead fails.

```
/(\/)(?!.?(?<=\1{2}))/
```

(feel free to use named captures)

or without captures:

```
/\/(?!.?(?<=\/\/))/
```

Comment: What a genius idea!!! (The key is to use lookahead with `.?` to *virtually* take a step forward to probe characters as needed)

Comment: So ingenious! Lookaround in regular expressions can actually be combined in this way!

Answer (score 0):

If all your inputs are URLs, this will do what you want:

```
/\/\/.+?(\/)/
```

And then capture the first group:

```js
url = 'https://example.com/...';
const matches = url.match(/\/\/.+?(\/)/);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Comment: No, the ultimate goal I'm trying to achieve is to use the "/" character only **1 time** in the regex literals. :)

Comment: @mamath If you get the right result returned from the pattern, why on Earth does it matter how many times the `/` character appears in your pattern?

Comment: For "generalization" :)